# Multiple Languages(English, French) on ASP.NET Page

Tags: asp.net, localization, internationalization, globalization

I was just wondering what is the best way to handle multiple languages on a web page?  Should I create an event in the load where I change the labels of all my controls to the approrpiate language text, or is there a better way?  I am using .NET framework, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For ASP.NET, use Resource files.  This will let you provide multilingual functionality and you can add translations without needing to recompile.

http://www.beansoftware.com/ASP.NET-Tutorials/Globalisation-Multilingual-CultureInfo.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You will want to look at the section of the MSDN documentation that deals with localization and globalization of ASP.NET apps:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6zyy3s9.aspx