# server time output with asp.net

Tags: asp.net, time

I want to show real server time on the page, not from user pc. Also would be great to use incrementing for seconds, to show day of the week in my language and month in my language.

Comment: What do you mean day of the week and month "in your language"?

Comment: So by 'incrementing seconds', you mean a live clock display on the page?

Answer (score 2):

`DateTime.Now` on the backend C# or VB code will give you the server time.

If I understand right, your incrementing clock is a live updating clock of the server time. What you can do is use the `DateTime.Now` value that will give you the server side time and then use client-side javascript to show the value.

This link here will show you how to create client javascript clock: http://www.ricocheting.com/code/javascript/html-generator/digital-clock

One problem may arise from this solution is the time difference between the call on the server time and when the javascript starts running the digital clock. This could be in milliseconds or off by 1-2 seconds which I don't see any issue unless you are running time sensitive application (which I recommend not using this solution anyway)

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime.Now` is the thing you want

Answer (score 0):

I think Steven had given some suggestion regarding to DateTime.

Since you had mentioned Multilingual in your page you can use Resource files. This will provide multilingual functionality and you can add translations without needing to recompile.

You can Find details [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/470366/multiple-languagesenglish-french-on-asp-net-page)